# flash motion question

Tags: flash

I am juststarting out with flash, and I know that motion tweening can automate simple things, but I would like to know if there are more ways to automate?

For example, the animation of the bird here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=As_-K8xGqLE

but going accross the page, I have basically been copying layers and moving the items in each layer. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

motion tweening only works for *moving* the object. Anything else will have to be an animation. You will have to create a MovieClip of the bird walking on the spot, and then use a motion tween to move the bird from point a to point b, while playing the MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provide doesn't require any Flash advanced knowledge but more patience. The guy draw is picture and he set up frame but frame. 1 frame = 1 picture.

Comment: The link is just an example for something similar I was doing in flash

Answer (score 0):

Using timeline animation you basically need one layer for every thing that moves independently. You can simplify this by making a movie clip symbol containing your object and putting all of the animation within that movie clip. And then you can animation the overall motion of the object on the main timeline.

The alternative way to do the animation using actionscript. Basically set a timer to fire at intervals and at each interval calculate where each each component of the animation needs to be and move it. A bit too much to go into here though.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, there are so many things you can do with script based animations. The answer you selected will work for your example, but you really should look into what code based animation can do for you. Check out these sites to get started.

First, check out [FuseKit](http://www.mosessupposes.com/Fuse/) for ActionScript 2.0 animations. You an build code based tween sequences.

There is also the [GoASAP](http://www.goasap.org/) animation platform which is an AS3 evolution of Fuse. But instead of being a limited class, it's a community driven Animation Platform with the goal of providing framework for Animation across multiple platforms (Flash/AS, SIlverlight/.NET, AfterEffects, 3D/Maya, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I've used both [FuseKit](http://www.mosessupposes.com/Fuse/) and [Tweenlite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/). FuseKit is very powerful and flexible. You can sequence very complicated animations.  I find that I can do most of my animations with TweenLite, so I suggest that if you're just starting out with Flash, you try Tweenlite.